# Unable to Remove Web.Config Nodes using Transform

Tags: visual-studio-2010, web-deployment, slowcheetah

I have a web.config containing rewrite rules like this:

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules><!-- Some rules here --></rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

For a particular deployment configuration, I want to remove the `<rewrite>` node entirely.

I tried doing this:

```
<system.web>
    <rewrite xdt:Transform="RemoveAll" />
</system.web>
```

Based on this documentation:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx

but the `<rewrite>` node remains.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Hmm I just tried this here is my transform file.

```xml
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">

  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite xdt:Transform="RemoveAll" />
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

And here is the result:
[image: illustrates difference of web.config after transform]
FYI preview provided by [SlowCheetah](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5).

I also packaged the web project and verified that the web.config indeed did not have the rewrite node. One thing to try here is to delete your obj\ folder and try again. Can you let me know the results?

Comment: D'oh!  I had my rule in `system.web` rather than `system.webServer`.  Carefully reading your answer made me realize the error of my ways :-)