# How do I remove a element from web.config using transformation?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-3

I would like to remove the entire element sessionState from my web.config using transformation.

I have tried , but the element wasn't removed.

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <system.serviceModel>
    <client>
      <!-- Some endpoints -->
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <sessionState xdt:Transform="Remove" />
  <system.net>
    <!--Email para ambiente de teste-->
    <mailSettings>

      <!-- SMTP CONFIG -->

    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Please include some code

Comment: And an example of the config file.

Comment: That looks correct.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to Remove Web.Config Nodes using Transform](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10388652/unable-to-remove-web-config-nodes-using-transform)

Answer (score 2):

Your transformation is correct.

I think the issue here is that you're expecting the transformation to take place when you **Build** the website in different modes(Debug\Release etc) but you need to understand that the transformation will only run when you **Publish** the web application.

You can test this by simply publishing to a folder on your local machine.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Thats not the case I'm trying to do that because I'm using Jenkins. Some parts are being transformed as expected, but the sessionState element, wasn't removed from the config.

Comment: To which config file did you apply this transformation?debug or release?

Comment: A custom one that I've created. It's working my problem is to remove that element.

Comment: When you publish your web application you need to select that specific configuration file under the Publish > Settings

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to use the `<system.web>` tag on my transformation. I realize it a while a go. Thanks for the responses.

`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
    <system.serviceModel>
       <client>
         <!-- Some endpoints -->
       </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
    <system.web>
      <sessionState mode="InProc" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" />
    </system.web>
    <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
        <-- SMTP CONFIG -->
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
</configuration>`
```